# Tableau Correlation using R

Tags: r, tableau-api

I am currently trying to do a Spearman's Rank Correlation in Tableau using the new R capability. I was able to get the correct code in R, but having trouble putting it in a form for Tableau to understand.

My data is grouped by code. So it is a Group Correlation. My code in R:

```
library (plyr)
ddply(mydata,"Code",summarise, corr=cor(Survey.1,Survey.2, method="spearman"))
```

How do I use the `Script_Real` in Tableau to give me that correlation?

Comment: I don't have access to Tableau to test, but [this article](http://www.simafore.com/blog/bid/120209/Integrating-Tableau-and-R-for-data-analytics-in-four-simple-steps) seems to explicitly address calculation correlation in R using Tableau.

Answer (score 3):

For those wanting to understand the coding. I have figured it out!

```
Script_Real("cor(.arg1,.arg2, method='spearman')",SUM([x]), Sum([y])).
```

Note: You need to have `ID:1,2,3,4,5,6,7` near your data in order for it to run the test. Then click the pill and compute using that `ID code`.

Comment: Could you explain what does `method=spearman` do ? is it required?

Answer (score 1):

One step you need is to configure the connection to R.
See the help menu ->Settings and Performance > Manage R Connection

If you are using Tableau server, that will need to know the connection path to RServe as well. See the online help.

Comment: Hey Alex, The problem isnt the connection. It is the actual code being put into Tableau for that system to understand the R code. I am not sure the mechanics of the code. There are many videos on forecasting, but none on correlation. That is where my problem lies.